# Take input from user and print the frequency of that term from the dataframe using for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I have titles of an author's publication in a csv file. I am reading that in python using the following code -

```
In[1]:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\orevo\\Desktop\\Python\\Publication Data\\author.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.iloc[:,3]
df1
```

which gives me this output -

```
Out[1]:

0     The adhesins of non-typeable Haemophilus influ...
1     Head and Neck Squamous Cell Carcinomas Are Cha...
2     Multitissue Transcriptomics Delineates the Div...
3     PTSD Blood Transcriptome Mega-Analysis: Shared...
4     Gene Expression Signatures in Tuberculosis Hav...
5     IFN-gamma Influences Epithelial Antiviral Resp...
6     Enhancing the Biological Relevance of Machine ...
7     Altered Epithelial Gene Expression in Peripher...
8     Transcriptomic Analysis Implicates the p53 Sig...
9     Sex-specific vitamin D effects on blood coagul...
10    Systems proteomic analysis reveals that cluste...
11    Quantitative Non-canonical Amino Acid Tagging ...
12    Gene expression analysis of TIL rich HPV-drive...
13    Lithium-responsive genes and gene networks in ...
14    Upregulated Glucose Metabolism Correlates Inve...
15    Hypothalamus proteomics from mouse models with...
16    Vitamin D Metabolites Inhibit Hepatitis C Viru...
17    Structural and Functional Changes of the Invar...
18    Acute psychological stress induces short-term ...
19    The interaction of genetic determinants in the...
20    Mixed effects of suberoylanilide hydroxamic ac...
21    Dose-responsive gene expression in suberoylani...
22    Are you also what your mother eats? Distinct p...
23    Gene networks specific for innate immunity def...
24    The promise of reverse vaccinology.
25    Gender-dependent differences in plasma matrix ...
26    Blood-based gene-expression biomarkers of post...
27    Replication competent virus as an important so...
28    Whole serum 3D LC-nESI-FTMS quantitative prote...
29    Maraviroc intensification in patients with sup...
```

I broke the title sentences into individual terms using this -

```
In[2]:    

df2 = []
for line in df1:
    for word in line.split():
        #temp = pd.DataFrame({'Title Terms' : word})
        df2.append({'Terms':word})
pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

which gives me the exact output I wanted -

```
Out[2]:

    Terms
0   The
1   adhesins
2   of
3   non-typeable
4   Haemophilus
5   influenzae.
6   Head
7   and
8   Neck
9   Squamous
10  Cell
11  Carcinomas
12  Are
13  Characterized
14  by
15  a
16  Stable
17  Immune
18  Signature
19  Within
20  the
21  Primary
22  Tumor
23  Over
24  Time
25  and
26  Space.
27  Multitissue
28  Transcriptomics
29  Delineates
```

The major issue comes here where I want the user to input any term so that he/she gets the frequency of that term in return if that term is found in the dataframe otherwise the output should show "Sorry! {Term that user entered} is not found in the database"

I have tried this code -

```
In[3]:

from string import *
import re
from nltk import FreqDist
from collections import Counter
term = input("Enter the term you are looking for:")
term = term.lower()
#counts = Counter(term)
found = True
#database = re.findall(r'\w+', open('C:\\Users\\orevo\\Desktop\\Python\\Publication Data\\Term\\Database of Terms.txt').read().lower())
database = pd.DataFrame(df2)

for term in database:
    #record = line.split('')
    record = record
    if record == term:
       found = True
       print("Found your word")
       break
    else:
       found = False
       print("We couldn't find your term")
       continue

if found == False:
    print("Sorry!Term is not found in the database")
else:
    print("Term :"+term+"\nNumber of times this term appears in the 
    database:"+str(Counter(term)))
```

but this is not giving the output I want and gives me this instead even though that term is in the dataframe -

```
Out[3]:     

Enter the term you are looking for:
In:    HIV
Out:   We couldn't find your term
       Sorry!Term is not found in the database
```

Pardon me for my 'not so good programming skills' if I had written something silly in the code but I am new to python and still learning things. Any help with this will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even I cannot see the term 'HIV' in your dataframe df2 which you are referring to as database later on. Also, you can use contains method to find if the string is present in the series or not. `df.Terms.str.contains('HIV')`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: @spideypack do you want to know just if it is in the text, or the frequency?

Comment: @user2695448 - That's because I haven't included all the terms here as there are total 65 titles which becomes a lot of terms when I am breaking the sentences. But there are some 'HIV' terms in the dataframe.

Comment: @Joe - If that term is in the dataframe it should print the frequency. If not it should print "Sorry! Term not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't we just use `value_counts`? You might need to do a bit more cleaning on `Terms` to remove the punctuation attached to some words. But once that is done this will work well. Using your `df` part above...

```
term = input("Enter the term you are looking for:")
term = term.lower()

vcounts = df.Terms.str.lower().value_counts()

try:
    print(term+':', vcounts[term])
except KeyError: 
    print('Sorry!', term, 'is not found in the database')

#Enter the term you are looking for: the
#the: 2

#Enter the term you are looking for: The
#the: 2

#Enter the term you are looking for: Oranges
#Sorry! oranges is not found in the database
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This is working for some of the terms and not working for the rest of them. I am trying to detect what is wrong that it's not giving the correct output for rest of the terms. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it so:

```
term = raw_input("Enter the term you are looking for:").lower()
df2['Terms'] = df2['Terms'].str.lower()
frequency = df2.loc[df.Terms == term, 'Terms'].count()
if frequency == 0:
    print("Sorry!Term is not found in the database")
else:
    print("Term :"+term+"\nNumber of times this term appears in the database:"+str(frequency))
```

Comment: I tried this but it's giving me this error - 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str'. The very first line of code is working fine though.

Comment: That works like a charm! It wasn't giving me the desired output before because some terms had punctuations after them like - {hiv.}{hiv,){hiv-} which is why it wasn't counting those terms. Thanks much!

Comment: Glad to help :) consider to accept the answer if you like